# webmasters tools not working - 0 Total Clicks

Tags: google-analytics, seo, google-search-console

Webmaster tools not working,I activated it but my total clicks is 0 .
My CMS is wordpress. My google analytics works fine!

[image]

My dashboard :

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

did you check your domain properties?
How you add domain in webmaster http://www.example.com or http://example.com
have you set preferred domain? 
submitted sitemap properly?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try deleting the property, add it again and verify using a different method